# Laravel realtionship groupBy

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am trying to get a relationship from a model but only 1 type of children.

Credito is my main model, and it has many archivos. Archivos has a field called 'parent_requisito_id', i want to extract all archivos but that i don't get repeated 'parent_requisito_id' looking for the newest entry of the single parent_requisito_id.

I have no idea into getting that output on a relation.

```
$files = $credito->archivos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [popular post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql) answers your question. But doing the same query with laravel relationship is a bit of work.

I don't know Spanish so I am gonna write some code in English after some translation:

```
credito: loan
archivo: archive (file)
requisito: requirement
```

A simple approach could be using Laravel Collection. From the discussion you got some timestamps issue. Lets use id instead of timestamps.

```
$files = $loan->archives()
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('parent_requirement_id')
    ->values();
```

Comment: it did work that it returned only 1 per parent_requisito_id, but not the latest

Comment: wait, i think its my bad since the one showing has no timestamps and the others do...

Comment: latest() considers created or modified timestamp?

Comment: im still getting the first instead of last, fixed the timestamps

Comment: another problem with that solution is that i get only 1 archive, not only 1 grouped by parent

Comment: `latest()` works on `created_at` by default, if you need to order other columns you can do `latest('column_name')`

Comment: A `Credito` model can have multiple `Archivos` with different `parent_requisito_id`?

Comment: @mdexp yes, thats the point, to get all the archivos but dont have repeated parent_requisito

Comment: @pato.llaguno I have updated my answer, including reference to another post. You want to have a look.

Comment: @kevin the problem with timestamp was a seed thing

Comment: it did work, ill reasearc around why keyBy gives me the latest, also have never used values() before on eloquent